# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: capacity was less than the current size. (Parameter 'value')

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain why I'm getting the following error from the following piece of code.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: capacity was less than the current size. (Parameter 'value')
```

I'm trying to take a semi-colon separated list which is then further comma separated.

The channelCodeToBoxesMapping parameter value expected would be something like this `01,0;02,1;03,1;05,1;06,0;07,1;08,1`.

Code:

```
private bool DetermineWhetherInSingleBoxModeFromChannelCodeMappings(string channelCodeToBoxesMapping)
{
    this.boxes.Clear();
    
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(channelCodeToBoxesMapping))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var channelCodeAndBoxPairs = channelCodeToBoxesMapping.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var pair in channelCodeAndBoxPairs)
    {
        var channelCodeAndBoxSplit = pair.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (channelCodeAndBoxSplit.Length != 2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        this.boxes.Add((BoxCount.Boxes)Convert.ToInt16(channelCodeAndBoxSplit[1]));
    }

    return this.boxes.Distinct().Count() == 1;
}
```

Notes:

`this.boxes` is a list of enums i.e. `List<BoxCount.Boxes>`.

Comment: What is the type of `this.boxes`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: @MartinCostello It's a list of enums i.e. List<BoxCount.Boxes>

Comment: At which line you get this error?

Comment: You are generating 2 string arrays here, can you please tell us the line of code that your stack trace is pinpointing you to?

Comment: Can you `Int16.TryParse(channelCodeAndBoxSplit[1], out var i)` instead of `Convert.ToInt16(channelCodeAndBoxSplit[1])` and see if the conversion succeeds?

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour It's the line with the 'Convert.ToInt16' and the issue is intermittent.

Comment: @YashGupta It's the line with the 'Convert.ToInt16'.

Comment: @mu88 Any reason why the issue may be intermittent?

Comment: Because sometimes the string isn't a 16-bit integer and sometimes it is?

Comment: @Bhav You know your data better than me  but checking the input for correctness (like `Int16.TryParse()`) and analyzing the results seems better to me than just blindly trusting in the correctness of the input

Comment: The input parameter has never changed.

Comment: @Bhav - you might be getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because the `channelCodeAndBoxSplit` array is probably empty (and hence may not contain anything at all at 1th index). Do you mind checking if this string array indeed contains something?